# Protobuf default values

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a registration form where login is entered. When I start typing, the text sent immediately to the server where the login is checked for availability.

The answer must be 0 or 1, true or false, depending on that I produce further action.
But 0/false is default fields values, and they are not sent, the field simply remains empty, fields is not at all (A field is sent on the wire if and only if it is not equal to its default value).

What can I do with it? I explicitly need to get an answer either 0 or 1. Of course, I use a string, but it is something wrong.

.proto

```
message InputChecking {
    string login       = 1;
    int32  loginStatus = 2;
    string mail        = 3;
    int32  mailStatus  = 4;
}

message RegistrationRequest {
    ...
}

message WrapperMessage {
    oneof msg {
        InputChecking mes_inputChecking = 1;
        RegistrationRequest mes_registrationRequest = 2;
    }   
}
```

.cpp

```
WrapperMessage wm; // protobuf message, is filled with data from the server

const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* inputCheckingField = wm.GetDescriptor()->FindFieldByName("mes_inputChecking");

if (wm.GetReflection()->HasField(wm, inputCheckingField)) // if inputCheckingField is
{
    // It says that such a field is, when he receives a message from the server with loginStatus = 0, but there are no fields

    const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* loginStatusField = wm.mes_inputchecking().GetDescriptor()->FindFieldByName("loginStatus");

    if (wm.mes_inputchecking().GetReflection()->HasField(wm.mes_inputchecking(), loginStatusField))
    {
            // It is only called when the login is different from 0
            Log("Login status = " + wm.mes_inputchecking().loginstatus()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not being clear about exactly the behaviour you want. If you want a bool, it does not matter whether the value is sent on the wire - only that the value received is the same as the one 'sent'. If you want a tristate, use an enum. Is this proto2 or proto3?

Comment: @RichardHodges I do not get the value 0 in general, and there is no field with him (loginStatusField). This is proto3. I'll try through enum,

Comment: same problem, ListFields method doesn't return field if it has value equaled default value

https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1772

Comment: Why are you using the reflection interface? Just test the value of field in the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use enums:

```
enum LoginStatus {
   LOGINSTATUS_INVALID = 0,
   LOGINSTATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE = 1,
   LOGINSTATUS_AVAILABLE = 2
}
```

This both makes the code more readable, and allows the third state (field missing in response) to be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this thread](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1606) I found a way to handle a nullable/default field, with the oneof wrapper it works.

```
message Foo {
  int x = 1;
  oneof v1 { 
     int32 value1 = 2; 
     bool  value2 = 3;
  }
}
```